# Are you more likely to find a monster in a cave during the day?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Because some monsters can't stay overground during the day or they will set fire it would make sense for them to stay underground. 
Since monsters spawn overground more during the night do they spawn underground more during the day?

I know that monsters spawn in low light but I swear half of the time when I'm exploring a cave and there will be no monsters (like during the day, overground), and then the other half I'm being attacked from multiple sides by literal hordes of monsters with no escape (like at night).

So is it safer to explore caves during the night like it is safer to explore the overworld during the day?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything on the gamepedia about this, so my guess would be: it doesn't matter. However, you can take into account that some mobs will go into caves when the night ends, so they could be slightly more filled then, or during night they might just stroll into a nearby cave. Other than that I'm not sure about what else could make mobs spawn in caves more often than another time.

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Yes I'm beginning to think finding an empty cave is just dumb luck. And the question would be more specific to the lower down caves not connected to above ground. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monsters spawn in low light levels only. If the area is above [light level 7](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light) monsters will not spawn. Any areas below that level (even down to 1 square) is a valid spawning space for hostile mobs.

When exploring caves, the tunnels you are exploring might not be the only areas within range to create valid spawning spaces.

[image]

[Mobs can spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Despawning) anywhere between 24 and 128 blocks from the player (outside of this range, they instantly despawn). So if you are exploring caves, there is a likely chance that mobs will spawn in another branch of the cave that you are not currently in.

So, to answer your question - Yes, you are *more likely* to find hostile mobs in caves during the day, but it does not guarantee any specific encounters.

Comment: I had to think about this, but it is true. I read up on how the spawning works and yes caves closer to the surface will have less monsters during day than night. Generally.

Comment: Also the matter of mob cap; after a certain number spawns, no more will spawn until some of that number are killed or despawned. So if you kill most mobs in caverns, the surface will take up most of mob cap and you'll only see few rare spawns in place of surface-despawned mobs at night. Then day comes, mobs on the surface burn in the sun and your caverns begin filling up again.